# Animated dashed line using SVG

Tags: html, css, svg

I try to find a way to draw an animated dash line like [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/ehan4/4/).

**The problem** with this solution is, that a black line is drawn underneath a dashed white line. The thing is, I want to have the middle parts (the spaces between the dashes) transparent, to put this animation on the top of a map image, not filled with color's (like white in this example).

I tried with different set ups of the stroke-dasharray and stroke-dashoffset attribute, but all this results were not like the way I search for.

Currently I embed a svg object directly in my HTML document. The svg tag includes the path tag, which is recommended for the path itself. The animation I try to realize with simple css animation key frames like:

```
    @keyframes dash
    {
        from
        {
            stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
        }
        to
        {
            stroke-dashoffset: 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have a look on this fairly good article from *Chris Coyier*: https://css-tricks.com/svg-line-animation-works/

Answer (score 0):

The space between the dashes is by default transparent.
Is there something your doing to change the color?

```css
svg {
  background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, red, blue);
}
svg circle {
  fill: pinK;
  stroke: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  stroke-width: 10px;
  stroke-dasharray: 5;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  animation: test 10s;
  -webkit-animation: test 10s;
}
@keyframes test {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 200;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes test {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 200;
  }
}
```

```html
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Yeah, normally the space between this dots are transparant, but in this shown example they are not. In my case I want to have a open dotted line on which each dot apears after another. The dots are sticked to the ground and not moving. Only the opacity of the dots is changing one after another. This example of _Chris Coyer_ are good and I read this thread, but with this technique I can only let the dots move on this path. [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29271646/1.jpg) you see what I'm trying to do. The path (red) is hidden and with each frame (numbers) one more dot (black) appears.